# Array of references in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I’ve read the reference documentation, but I can’t figure out how to dereference the array references inside my array.
Don’t understand why `@{$HoA{$cols[0]}}` prints only the length of the array either. Any clarification is much appreciated.

`file.txt`:

```
    aa      bb
    bb      cc
```

The program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

# my $filename = "file.txt";
my @newarray;

my %HoA = (
        aa        => [ "GAT_1", "GAT_2", "GAT_3", "GAT_4" ],
        bb        => [ "GAT_6", "GAT_1", "GAT_5", "GAT_4", "GAT_2" ],
        cc        => [ "GAT_6", "GAT_4", "GAT_3", "GAT_1", "GAT_2" ],
      );

open (FILE, '<' ,"$filename") or print "$filename does not exist\n";


while (<FILE>) {
    my @cols = split;
    $cols[0] = $HoA{ $cols[0] };
    #$cols[0] = @{$HoA{ $cols[0]} };
    $cols[1] = $HoA{ $cols[1] };
    #$cols[1] = @{$HoA{ $cols[1] }};
    push ( @newarray, join( " ", @cols ));
}

close FILE;

print Dumper(\@newarray);
```

This is my expected output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            [
              'GAT_1',
              'GAT_2',
              'GAT_3',
              'GAT_4'
            ],
            [
              'GAT_6',
              'GAT_1',
              'GAT_5',
              'GAT_4',
              'GAT_2'
            ],
        [
              'GAT_6',
              'GAT_1',
              'GAT_5',
              'GAT_4',
              'GAT_2'   
            ],
            [
              'GAT_6',
              'GAT_4',
              'GAT_3',
              'GAT_1',
              'GAT_2'
            ],

          ]
        ];
```

This is my actual output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'ARRAY(0x7f80110060e8) ARRAY(0x7f801102eb58)',
          'ARRAY(0x7f801102eb58) ARRAY(0x7f801102f308)'
        ];
```

Comment: Re "*I can’t figure out how to dereference the array references inside my array*", Technically, are you are deferencing it. What output are you expecting?

Comment: Re "*Don’t understand why `@{$HoA{$cols[0]}}` prints only the length of the array*", `@{$HoA{$cols[0]}}` doesn't print anything. `@a` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in the array. As such, `@{ REF }` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in the referenced array.

Comment: what is your expected output?  your join is treating array references as strings, but without expected output it is hard to know what you should be doing instead

Comment: I was expecting that the keys in my file were completely replaced by the corresponding arrays in the values of my hash of arrays, but what I got instead were the references pointing to those arrays. Probably not well explained, my apologies.

Comment: If that happens in scalar context, is there a way of performing the substitution in a list context? That's what I couldn't figure out how to do.

Comment: It's still hard to see exactly what you wanted the output to look like.  Why not edit your post and add sections to show the complete "Expected Output" and "Actual Output"?

Comment: @George Adams, I've edited the post with those sections.

Comment: It is almost always wrong to put a scalar variable in quotes. Use `$filename` in preference to `"$filename"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big problem is this line:

```
    push ( @newarray, join( " ", @cols ));
```

`join` is inherently a string operation: `@cols` is an array of references, which `join` then dutifully stringifies so that it can join them with `" "`.

It seems like what you really want is probably this:

```
    push ( @newarray, [@cols] );
```

where the `[ ... ]` notation creates a new anonymous array (in this case populated with the values in `@cols`) and returns a reference to to it.

Additionally, instead of this:

```
    $cols[0] = $HoA{ $cols[0] };
```

(which causes `@newarray` and `%HoA` to end up containing references to the same underlying arrays), you *may* want this:

```
    $cols[0] = [ @{$HoA{ $cols[0] }} ];
```

(such that `@newarray` ends up with completely independent arrays that simply start out with the same data as what's in `%HoA`). This depends on whether you're planning to modify any of the arrays afterward.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly it!